# SQL Syntax Error in PHP code - adding together two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting this syntax error in my MySQL code within a PHP file. I'm simply trying to increment/add to the value already in the table with this time variable. If anyone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

PHP:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Aircraft
SET MaintenanceFlightTime = (MaintenanceFlightTime + $MaintenanceDuration),
WHERE AircraftID = $AircraftID";
```

Error:

```
UPDATE Aircraft SET MaintenanceFlightTime = (MaintenanceFlightTime + 00:10:00), WHERE AircraftID = 8
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':10:00), WHERE AircraftID = 8' at line 2
```

Comment: Ok so what data type is the `MaintenanceFlightTime` column

Comment: The + won't work unless those are both numbers.  You're probably better off doing the math first, then send the result through the UPDATE.

Comment: Just delete the extra comma `), WHERE`

Comment: Maybe I could effect an introduction to the manual for [`ADDTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime)

Comment: The data type of the column is `Time` and removing the comma does not remove the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just add a string like '01:01:01' to a time column but you can use `ADDTIME()`

```
$MaintenanceDuration = '00:10:00';

$sql = "UPDATE Aircraft
        SET MaintenanceFlightTime = ADDTIME(MaintenanceFlightTime, '$MaintenanceDuration')
        WHERE AircraftID = $AircraftID";
```